# How to disable cut, copy and paste operation for password tag in html

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head><title>Practice</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function disableCopy() {
      alert("You cannot perform Copy");
      return false;
    }
    function disablePaste() {
      alert("You cannot performing Paste");
      return false;
    }
    function disableCut() {
      alert("You cannot perform Cut");
      return false;
    }
    function disableContextMenu() {
      alert("You cannot perform right click via mouse as well as keyboard");
      return false;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea rows=10 cols=50 oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncontextmenu="return false">
    Enter Text here......
  </textarea>
  <br/>
  Password<input type="password" oncopy="return disableCopy();" id="pwd" onpaste="return disablePaste();" oncut="return disableCut();" oncontextmenu="return disableContextMenu();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Hello Friends I am fresher learning Javascript ,I came across an issue in password tag while I am performing operations like copy, cut and paste my password in the above example. Here I have made use of onCopy,onPaste,and onCut events for disabling cut, copy and paste operations by writing a Javascript functions as shown in code. But when I run this same example in Mozilla Browser on each event function gets executed as expected with alerts but when I run the same example in Chrome Browser or Internet Explorer I don't get alert's. Could anyone please help me to solve this problem or could anyone please provide an alternate solution such that same example can tested across all the three browsers i.e Mozilla, Chrome, Internet Explorer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Keep in mind that a user can simply deactivate js. So any JS protection is not reliable anyway. With that in mind: Do you really need this kind of feature?

Comment: adding on newBee: I always hate when a program/website tries to force me to input my data in a certain way. I hate when I cannot use copy/paste. I would avoid such websites in the future, if possible.

Comment: Don't do this. Really, really, don't do this. If I can't paste my password into a field then I'm encouraged to use a password that is short and easy to type. That means a relatively insecure password.

Comment: I totally agree but if the client wants, then the client gets. If they pay for it, then you can't really argue back.

Comment: With Help of this tut, you can - http://www.kvcodes.com/2014/03/disabling-textbox-cut-copy-and-paste-operations/

Comment: @DarrenWillows - In a case like this, you may be "ethically obligated" to ague back at the person distributing the requirement, but as you said, it will often get you nowhere...  So why did Chetan get downvoted so bad?  I know everyone says you're not supposed to do that, but I thought his question was reasonably clear...

Answer (score 0):

Working in Firefox and other latest browsers.

Stopping this functionality is a bad idea, but I know clients can ask for this sort of crap to happen.

```
<input type="text" onselectstart="return false" onpaste="return false;" onCopy="return false" onCut="return false" onDrag="return false" onDrop="return false" autocomplete=off/>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLrqwhL8/)

Comment: Good answer. But, i think he wants an alert as well

Answer (score 0):

Jquery:

```
 $('#your_password_field_id').bind("cut copy paste",function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
          });
```

or javascript:

```
<input type="password" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" onpaste="return false">
```

Comment: He is not asking for a solution with jQuery library!

Answer (score 0):

The code shown below will help you in preventing copy/cut/paste on any element you want.

Live example is on following link

[enter link description here](http://jsbin.com/uyuzo/739/edit?html,css,js,output)

```js
$('#XlsFileRenamed').removeAttr('disabled');
$('#txtInput').bind("paste",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Disable Cut,Copy and Paste Demo</title>
  <script  type="text/javascript"
          src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js">
    </script>
How to copy text from one infddput textbox to multiple textboxes using jQuery
<script type="text/javascript">

  
  function disableValidation(element)
  {
    $(element).on("cut copy
                  ",function(e) {
       return true;
    });

    $(element).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
      return true;
    });
    
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <br />
  <span> Enter Something </span>
  <textarea id="txtInput" onClick="disableValidation('#txtInput')"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```